# NoClassDefFoundError in Tomcat but not in a Standalone application for a dynamically created java class

Tags: java, tomcat, code-generation, classloader, noclassdeffounderror

I have a class foo that my application generates, then compiles using the command line, and then loads using a custom classloader.

The reason this had to be done is that the application "generates java code" for the class foo that it then incorporates into its own program using a classloader. As an application this works fine.

Now I am trying to port this to tomcat.

The custom classloader loads this file from outside of tomcat (this may be an issue but I have not seen an error message about that, the application generates, writes the file for foo.java, calls javac to build it, and the classloader certainly finds foo.class since it can't find fooparent.

fooparent is already in the application, I see it in the jar file that is loaded by tomcat.

Again, as an application this works.

Now,

foo extends fooparent.

I read:
*ClassLoaders are hierarchical, meaning your dynamically loaded class has access to all of its parent's classes, but the parent doesn't have any direct access to its classes.* But I am not told what is the solution?

It seems that in tomcat, it loads the foo class and then gives a NoClassDefFoundError for the "fooparent". It seems like the parent of foo was loaded before by a parent classloader but my custom classloader is not visible to what other classloaders have already loaded to be seen and in a sense integrated.

I am trying to find out if I am trying to do the impossible and if I should abandon this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not dealing with the classloader chierarchy. Please read this [enter link description here](http://www.onjava.com/lpt/a/5586), [Understanding The Tomcat Classpath - Common Problems And How To Fix Them](http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-classpath) and [Tomcat Class Loader HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)